# How to add envoy proxy to a deployment

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

I want to add envoy proxy to an existing Kubernetes deployment as a sidecar. I tried following multiple blog posts and that did not seem to help. I was wondering if anyone has done it, and if so, how to?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You must restart the deployment.

from istio [manual](https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/):

> If you are using manual sidecar injection, use the following command
>
> $ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f bookinfo.yaml)
>
> The istioctl kube-inject command is used to manually modify the
> bookinfo.yaml file before creating the deployments as documented [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/#istioctl-kube-inject).
>
> If you are using a cluster with automatic sidecar injection enabled,
> label the default namespace with istio-injection=enabled
>
> $ kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
>
> Then simply deploy the services using kubectl
>
> $ kubectl apply -f bookinfo.yaml

Answer (score 1):

To add [Kun Li's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777604/476917), if your case is the kubernetes cluster already has many services running, it is safer to do that by set the `autoInjection` policy as `disabled` by default, and let the service owner set it explicitly that it wants to use istio side car.

To do that, you have to:

- set the Istio (via helm installation) helm installation flag `--global.proxy.autoInject=disabled --sidecarInjectorWebhook.enabled=true`.
- then in your namespace, set `kubectl label namespace bar istio-injection=enabled`

The `--sidecarInjectorWebhook.enabled=true` and labeling your namespace: means that the istio sidecar injector webhook is activated for your namespace. But then, since you specify the `global.proxy.autoInject=disabled`, it won't inject any pods. So, the service owner have to define explicitly the pod's annotation (in your deployment yaml file) like below:

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
```

To check your istio's sidecar injection policy,

> kubectl get cm istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system -o yaml

take a look at `data.config` value, it should contains `policy: disable` or `policy: enabled`.

Reference:
- https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/sidecar-injection/#policy
- personal hands on (I've tried it)